# C# loops through 24 hours every 30 minutes

Tags: c#

I am wondering how I would loop through a datetime or any type of variable to go from 12:00AM to 11:59PM every 30 Mins?

So I need a variable that shows times in 12HR format (01:00PM, 09:00AM) and everytime I loop through it, to add 30 mins to the time? I then need to use this value in a string.

The time needs to start at 10:00AM

Comment: Why loop?  From your description, it would be easy to determine what the string should be at any time of the day?

Comment: @Paddy - I think the OP want's to loop through every value from 10:00AM - 9:59AM incrementing by 30 minutes. Though, admittedly, I'm not really sure. The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

And there is always LINQ

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var clockQuery = from offset in Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
                 select start.AddMinutes(30 * offset);
foreach (var time in clockQuery)
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
```

... LINQ + FUNC (for parameterized start)

```
Func<DateTime, IEnumerable<DateTime>> clockQuery = start =>
    from offset in Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
    select start.AddMinutes(30 * offset);
foreach (var time in clockQuery(DateTime.Today))
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
```

... or if you just want the TimeSpan offsets ...

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var clockQuery = from offset in Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
                 select TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30 * offset);
foreach (var time in clockQuery)
    Console.WriteLine((start + time).ToString("hh:mm tt"));
```

Comment: IS there a way to say what time i want to start with in the foreach?

Comment: I think it should be `Enumerable.Range(0, 47)` as the 0..48 would give you 49 times which runs into the next day with 24.5 hours.

Comment: That second value is a count not a bound.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHalfHours(this DateTime dt)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        DateTime time = dt;
        while(true)
        {
            yield return time;
            time.Add(ts);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for implementing as IEnumerable. Isn't that while(true) gonna make it enum forever though?

Comment: yes, it's an infinite sequence- certainly can't do a `.ToList()` on this one but you could do `dt.GetHalfHours().Take(5)` i.e. to get the next 5 "half hours" - all works because Linq is lazy

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
DateTime timeloop = new DateTime(0);
timeloop = timeloop.Add(new TimeSpan(10, 00, 0)); //start at 10:00 AM

            for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
            {
                string time =timeloop.ToString("hh:mm tt");           //print it as 1:30 PM
                timeloop = timeloop.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));      //add 30 minutes
                               }
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime can do simple arithmetic:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
time = time + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

Causes time to be incremented by one minute.

You can use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class and increase the DateTime by whatever amount of time is appropriate once per [tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx).  If exactness is important here there are other, more appropriate timer classes.

There are other static methods on the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
var times = new List<string>();
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
for (var i = today; i < tomorrow; i = i.AddMinutes(30))
{
    times.Add(i.ToShortTimeString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime time = new DateTime(2011,02,22,10,0,0);
        List<String> times = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        {
            time = time.AddMinutes(30);
            times.Add(time.ToString());
        }
```

This might do what you need

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
    int workCount = 0;
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1800000);   // every half hour
    timer.AutoReset = true;

    timer.Elapsed += (src, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        if(++workCount == 48)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    };

    timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime startDate = endDate.AddDays(-1);

        while (startDate.AddMinutes(30) <= endDate)
        {
            string sdate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            string edate = startDate.AddMinutes(29).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

            string display = string.Format("{0} - {1}", sdate, edate);

            Console.WriteLine(display);
            startDate = startDate.AddMinutes(30);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks